# AndroidTest duplicate file from main source set

Tags: android, android-testing

So I have my VeryCoolClass in main source set.
For instrumentation tests I'd like to use modified copy of that class, but I don't want to modify class at main.

I put modified version of my VeryCoolClass at the same classpath under androidTest folder (assuming when running tests system will chose this one).

It's working something strange - sometimes works, sometimes not and always give a warning about duplicate class found.

Is there a way to do what I want?